# Решить проблему записи телефонных разговоров с линии (голоса обоих собеседников) на устройствах Sony с версии Android 6 и выше

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-ndk, запись

На устройствах Sony до Android 6 запись телефонных разговоров производилась с источником записи *MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL* после обновления на Android 6 запись не может производиться с линии. В логах пишет, что нужно разрешение *android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT*, но оно не может быть получено для сторонних приложений.
Сообщение из логов при попытке сделать запись с линии:

```
[ 05-10 15:33:46.729   375: 4179 E/ ] Request requires android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT
```

Эту проблему можно как то обойти т.к. несколько приложений в Google Play это сделали без использования Root прав.

Из логов я выяснил, что эти приложения сначала начинают запись с источника записи *MediaRecorder.AudioSource.Mic*(c микрофона) затем как то переключают источник записи на *MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL* (на линию):

Сообщение в логах (установка источника записи на Mic):

```
D/audio_hw_primary: in_set_parameters: enter: kvpairs=input_source=1;routing=-2147483644
```

Сообщение в логах (установка источника записи на VOICE_CALL):

```
D/audio_hw_primary: in_set_parameters: enter: kvpairs=input_source=4;routing=-2147483584;format=1
```

Я предполагаю что они это делают нативным кодом т.к. стандартными методами мне это сделать не удалось. Я попытался установить параметры через *AudioMаnager*:

```
AudioManager aManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
aManager.setParameters("kvpairs=input_source=4;routing=-2147483584;format=1");
```

но в логах вижу, что вызывается функция *adev_set_parameters* а не *in_set_parameters*:

```
05-12 11:41:02.462 375-17526/? D/audio_hw_primary: adev_set_parameters: enter: kvpairs=input_source=4;routing=-2147483584;format=1
```

В интернете нашел исходники этого файла: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/qcom/audio/+/7c57a3a8ab8d526c074bcc373e8cba2fa06b4f23/hal/audio_hw.c

У меня есть предположения как решить этот вопрос но я в этом не уверен: можно добавить *audio_hw.c* в приложение и использовать его через NDK (вызвать функцию *in_set_parameters*).

*Оригинал вопроса*: https://bitbucket.org/ViktorDegtDev/cvrecorder/issues/1/sony-android-6

Comment: а в шестерке вы пробовали програмно запросить android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT?

Comment: Естественно! Но это ни какого результата не дает, оно не доступно для сторонних приложений.

Comment: чувак ты решил проблему?

Comment: @PeterDroid Конечно!

Comment: @ВикторДегтярев рыть в сторону in_set_parameters логично? Не прошу код , подсказку хоть , пожалуйста.

Comment: @PeterDroid мой скайп viktor_degtyarev

Comment: Есть библиотека для записи телефонных разговоров на Android 6 https://github.com/ViktorDegtyarev/CallRecLib

Comment: @PeterDroid Посмотри либу github.com/ViktorDegtyarev/CallRecLib